# If dbo.DatabaseIntegrityCheck fails, what happens, i.e. how am I notified?

Tags: sql-server, ola-hallengren

I'm new to [Ola Hallengren's MaintenanceSolution](https://ola.hallengren.com/) (which looks fantastic), and DBA-ing generally. I've created a job to run `dbo.DatabaseIntegrityCheck` (weekly against ALL_DATABASES). If there are errors found by `DBCC CHECKDB` does this cause the proc to error and therefore the Job to fail, so I'll get a notification in the normal way from my job failing? Will it continue to verify the integrity of all the other databases or does it stop on the first problem DB it finds?

I couldn't find any notes on the [overview](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-integrity-check.html), sorry if I missed something obvious.

Comment: You can always read the script to find out :) Always good to do before installing on your servers!

Comment: Thanks @LowlyDBA, very helpful. 2000 LOC later ... still non-trivial to assess exactly what happens in error scenarios, eg what error codes are returned by a DBCC CHECKDB statement in different scenarios? I don’t know and wouldn’t want to try to set up the test scenarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The job will continue. And it will fail (in the end), so it is up to you to get notified when a (this) job fails. For instance send an email on job failure.